# Applying one-time bindings to custom element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a simple directive—`<call-card>`—and I'm wondering how to apply one-time bindings to it, as practice to optimize future directives.

This directive's definition object looks like:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: 'callCard',
    scope: {
        headline: '=',
        subtitle: '=?',
        highPriority: '=?',
        onFilterClick: '='
    }
}
```

And its template:

```
<div class="headline"
     ng-class="{ 'high-priority': !!callCard.highPriority }">
     {{ callCard.headline }}
</div>
<div class="subtitle"
     ng-if="callCard.subtitle">
     {{ callCard.subtitle }}
</div>
<div class="filter"
     ng-click="callCard.onFilterClick()">
</div>
```

It's used like:

```
<call-card ng-repeat="row in cardList.rows"
           headline="row.headline"
           subtitle="row.subtitle"
           on-filter-click="cardList._.bind(cardList.onFilterRowClick, cardList, row)"></call-card>
```

The collection `cardList.rows` may change in `cardList`, but the properties that get passed into `<call-card>` directive will never change after the `<call-card>` is created.

Given this scenario, should I change the bindings passed into `<call-card>`, the bindings in the `<call-card>` template, or both?

For example—changing the bindings passed into `<call-card>`:

```
<call-card ng-repeat="row in ::cardList.rows"
           headline="::row.headline"
           subtitle="::row.subtitle"
           on-filter-click="::cardList._.bind(cardList.onFilterRowClick, cardList, row)"></call-card>
```

For example—changing the bindings in the `<call-card>` template:

```
<div class="headline"
     ng-class="{ 'high-priority': !!::callCard.highPriority }">
     {{ ::callCard.headline }}
</div>
<div class="subtitle"
     ng-if="::callCard.subtitle">
     {{ ::callCard.subtitle }}
</div>
<div class="filter"
     ng-click="::callCard.onFilterClick()">
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think both, because while the properties (bindings) to the directive may never change, you can still change these values from within the directive's inner scope

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this?

```
app.directive('myOnceBind', function ($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {
      myOnceBind: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var stopWatch = $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $parse($attrs.myOnceBind)($scope.$parent);
      }, function (n) {
        if (angular.isString(n)) {
          stopWatch();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9gyFgWO2i9fiXWuitStI?p=preview)

Note, that this will work only for string (your case).